# two opponent elements word example water and fire

Tags: word-request

What is the English word which describes the opponent of two elements? Am I asking the right question?

For example, the water `the english word` fire. I don't really know how to describe but here are more example.

- Water versus Fire
- Lava versus Ice
- Volcano versus Ice Mountain

Like when we threw the water into the fire, the fire will be disappeared. By the way,
was when we threw Ice into the Lava, the Lava will be disappeared, wasn't it?

Comment: Do you mean "counterpart"? Or "opposite"?

Comment: If you throw any size piece of ice, that you can lift, into a big enough lake of lava, the lava will win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for the word **counteract**.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/counteract) has

> to reduce or remove the effect of something unwanted by producing an opposite effect
> *Drinking a lot of water counteracts the dehydrating effects of hot weather*

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counteract) has

> to make ineffective or restrain or neutralize the usually ill effects of by means of an opposite force, action, or influence
> *a drug used to counteract fatigue*

In the game [rock paper scissors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_paper_scissors)

- rock counteracts scissors
- paper counteracts rock
- scissors counteracts paper

In the examples,

> Water counteracts fire.